Arborvitae tree dies within 3 days of insecticide spray
Our healthy, well established 17 foot arborvitae tree was sprayed during routine tree maintenance. One day later, it started to turn brown. In one week it was dead.
They are citing lack of water. Doesn't make sense.There arborvitaes all over our area, and they are not dead. A sample was take to The Department of Agriculture, it showed no sign of herbicide damage. The sample they took was already dead!
Besides sueing, what can we do? Help!

What was it sprayed with?

Can you add a picture of the arborvitae?

If the sample was taken after one week. then certain herbicides, such as dicamba, will not be found on the sample. I know you wrote insecticide, but I've not heard of any insecticide (which tend to be neurotoxins) killing any plant material. My opinion without any more info is that the arb was sprayed with an herbicide by mistake. Yeah. their "not enough water" for an established arb is ridiculous and may indicate that they know they screwed up and aren't willing to take responsibility for it.

What other trees were sprayed at the same time in the same vicinity, and did they die?   What about other foliage near the tree?      What country are you in?  (In my country we can demand they make good under consumer law).   Suing is not neccessarily bad/hard if you do it through your local small claims court.

The Sprayers must have mistakenly sprayed something other than insecticides. Not your mistake but theirs, and theirs to repair.
This technique worked for me in a different setting.

Write a scathing, but level-headed review on Google or Yelp, but do not post it.
Snap the screen and send it to the Sprayers.
Ask them if they'd like to work something out before you post. Perhaps you want them to replace the shrubs with the tallest available ones at their expense. Then you won't post.
If all else fails, post whenever you want, but you lose leverage at that point, as the threat is more potent than the posting.

Point is that consumers make idle threats all the time about retaliating online. And they don't. And the business knows it. Here, you have a fait accompli, not a rant. Effective.

Or just they didn't clean the devices. In any case, not professional behaviour.

Yup. Using the same sprayer for herbicides and insecticides is very prone to killing plants, or perhaps just the first plant, as the herbicide left in the uncleaned (or poorly cleaned) hose sprays out. Most careful applicators have specific sprayers for specific uses to prevent this problem.
